# Error: Cannot enqueue Query after fatal error

Tags: mysql, node.js

Есть код:

```
function isAuth(socket, next) {
    // Куча другого кода
    if (hash == sig) {
        connection.query('SELECT avatar_url FROM fm_profiles WHERE user_id = ?', [handshakeData._query.user_id], function(err, rows) {
            if (err) throw err;
            var ava = rows[0].avatar_url;
            handshakeData.avatar = ava;
        });
        handshakeData.nick = handshakeData._query.username;
        handshakeData.user_id = handshakeData._query.user_id;
        handshakeData.mode = handshakeData._query.mode;
        next();

        return;
    }
    next(new Error('not authorized'));
}
```

Через некоторое время он пишет следующую ошибку:

```
Error: Cannot enqueue Query after fatal error.
```

Есть скрипт автоматического поднятия MySQL, но после этой ошибки он не работает:

```
function initializeConnection(config) {
    function addDisconnectHandler(connection) {
        connection.on("error", function (error) {
            if (error instanceof Error) {
                if (error.code === "PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST") {
                    console.error(error.stack);
                    console.log("Lost connection. Reconnecting...");

                    initializeConnection(connection.config);
                } else if (error.fatal) {
                    throw error;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    var connection = mysql.createConnection(config);

    // Add handlers.
    addDisconnectHandler(connection);

    connection.connect();
    return connection;
}

var connection = initializeConnection({
    host        : '127.0.0.1',
    user        : 'root',
    password    : 'xxx',
    database    : 'xxx',
});
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну еще бы этот скрипт работал. Вы же при ошибке создаете новый `connection`... и забываете его, оставляя всех работать со старым!

Вообще, использование единого соединения с БД в веб-сервере - странная идея. Ведь параллельно выполняется много запросов от разных пользователей - так что, при падении соединения из-за одного пользователя улетают все?

Даже создание соединения на каждый запрос - и то выглядит лучше. А еще в используемой вами библиотеке есть [пулы соединений](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/#pooling-connections) - которые вполне пригодны для использования.